# How to implement the Vieta's formula in Mathematica in the general case?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

I have list of $N$ roots ($r_1, r_2, ..., r_N$) and would like to restore some coefficient $a_k$ of the original polynomial. Vieta's formula is what I need, but I don't understand how to implement it in Mathematica in the general case.

Following [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas):

$$
\sum_{1 \le i_1 \le i_2 \le \dots \le i_k \le N } \prod_{j=1}^{k}r_{i_j} = (-1)^k \frac{a_{N-k}}{a_N}
$$

We can, of course, write the polynomial in factor form and apply the Expand-function, but this will take a long time in the case of a large number of roots.

I would like to build some kind of function like: a[k_, roots_] := ...

Comment: Look at the docs for `SymmetricPolynomial[]`. The last two examples in the "Properties and Relations" section should be useful.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a snippet of Mathematica code for demonstration of Vieta's formula.

$$
\sum_{1 \leq i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k \leq n}\left(\prod_{j=1}^k r_{i_j}\right)=(-1)^k \frac{a_{n-k}}{a_n}
$$

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 4;
equation[k_Integer /; k >= 1 && k <= n, n_Integer] := 
 SymmetricPolynomial[k, Array[Subscript[r, #] &, n]] == (-1)^k*
   Subscript[a, n - k]/Subscript[a, n]
equation[#, n] & /@ Range[1, n, 1] // MatrixForm
```

$$
r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4=-\frac{a_3}{a_4}\\
r_1 r_2+r_3 r_2+r_4 r_2+r_1 r_3+r_1 r_4+r_3 r_4=\frac{a_2}{a_4}\\
r_1 r_2 r_3+r_1 r_4 r_3+r_2 r_4 r_3+r_1 r_2 r_4=-\frac{a_1}{a_4}\\
r_1 r_2 r_3 r_4=\frac{a_0}{a_4}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!